# How to specify the default output encoding for libxml2 to prevent overzealous entity-escaping in attributes?

Tags: php, attributes, libxml2, html-entities

It seems that this problem bites me again. I've asked some time ago something similar on dba thinking it is only a PostgreSQL problem, but alas now it bothers me in php. But the common thing is the underlying libxml2 library.

My experience leads me to believe that some operations will convert all non-Latin characters in attributes values (and only in attribute values) into escaping-entities, i.e. `&#xHEX;`. It looks like as if inside an attribute, the writer forgets that it should default to UTF-8 and assumes ASCII. There are some manipulations that can be done to mitigate this problem (as shown in the code below), but it isn't always feasible (like inside PostgreSQL's stored function).

The code showing the problem

```
<?php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root><элемент атрибут="&quot;знач.&quot;">текст</элемент></root>
XML;
$r = new XMLReader();
$r->xml($xml);
do {
    $r->read();
} while ($r->nodeType != XMLReader::ELEMENT);
$r->read();
echo $r->readOuterXml(), "\n";
$n = $r->expand(new DomDocument());
echo $n->ownerDocument->saveXml($n), "\n";
$n = $r->expand(new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'));
echo $n->ownerDocument->saveXml($n), "\n";
?>
```

outputs

```
<элемент атрибут="&quot;&#x437;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x447;.&quot;">текст</элемент>
<элемент атрибут="&quot;&#x437;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x447;.&quot;">текст</элемент>
<элемент атрибут="&quot;знач.&quot;">текст</элемент>
```

*The result I am after is the last one.*

**Thus the question:** is there any setting or something in libxml2 to somehow globally set the default output encoding despite the input or even the omitted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in libxml2 which I [just fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/commit/39fbfb4fd08eae88d4b0c15f3a8ac33babc740e6).

Note that you still have to provide an explicit UTF-8 encoding in the XML declaration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a pity there is no universal way to set output encoding, still this will help in time. BTW, can you look at point 1 of [my dba post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217184/problems-encountered-by-me-while-working-with-xml-in-postgresql)? The result there is the same, but the culprit is an XPath evaluation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IvanUstûžanin Maybe the Postgres problem can be fixed by always adding an XML declaration with UTF-8 encoding: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help: `SELECT (xpath('*', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><r><э язык="рус">текст</э></r>'))[1]::text` still returns `<э язык="&#x440;&#x443;&#x441;">текст</э>`.

Comment: @IvanUstûžanin Maybe this can be fixed in libxml2 as well, see my post on the [mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2018-September/msg00015.html).

Comment: If it can be ever done, it will be a blessing. I hope you can manage this. And about breaking things, the current situation seems more broken than not, moreover nowadays using xml-documents in a non-UTF-8 context is almost a nonsense.